# ValueError file not found after setting output - Biopython

Tags: python, parsing, biopython, blast

```
from Bio.Blast.Applications import NcbiblastpCommandline

blastp_cline = NcbiblastpCommandline(cmd="~ncbi-blast.2.10.1+bin/blastp", query="human.fa", db="mouse.fa", evalue=.0001, out="output.xml", outputfmt=5)
blastp_cline

from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML


result_handle = open(homoutput.xml)
blast_records - NCBIXML.parse(results_handle)

for br in blast_records:
    for alignments in br.alignments:
        for hsp in alignments.hsps:
            if hsp.expect < 1e-107:
                print (alignments.title)
                print (alignments.length)
                print (hsp.expect)

                print (hsp.query)

                print (hsp.match)
```

This is the whole error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parseBlast.py", line 5, in <module>
    blastp_cline = NcbiblastpCommandline(cmd="~ncbi-blast.2.10.1+bin/blastp", query="human.fa", db="mouse.fa", evalue=.0001, out="output.xml", outputfmt=5)
  File "/home/minhlam/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Bio/Blast/Applications.py", line 512, in __init__
    _NcbiblastMain2SeqCommandline.__init__(self, cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/home/minhlam/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Bio/Blast/Applications.py", line 438, in __init__
    _Ncbiblast2SeqCommandline.__init__(self, cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/home/minhlam/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Bio/Blast/Applications.py", line 392, in __init__
    _NcbiblastCommandline.__init__(self, cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/home/minhlam/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Bio/Blast/Applications.py", line 308, in __init__
    _NcbibaseblastCommandline.__init__(self, cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/home/minhlam/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Bio/Blast/Applications.py", line 115, in __init__
    AbstractCommandline.__init__(self, cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/home/minhlam/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Bio/Application/__init__.py", line 295, in __init__
    self.set_parameter(key, value)
  File "/home/minhlam/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Bio/Application/__init__.py", line 410, in set_parameter
    raise ValueError("Option name %s was not found." % name)

**ValueError: Option name outputfmt was not found.**
```

I'm checking my directory and no output was made so the second blast part doesn't even work. I'm working with 2 local files: human.fa and mouse.fa. I'm suppose to parse through human.fa to find homologs in the mouse.fa database with Blast and print out human sequence ID, mouse ID, similar homologs, and corresponding alignment.

Comment: Sounds like `outputfmt` is not a valid argument to `NcbiblastpCommandline()`.  Why are you using it?

Comment: oh, it's outfmt=5 for xml. I changed it but still error
The output file isn't made so a NameError: name 'output' is not defined. The first part of commandline doesn't produce an xml file at all

Comment: ```from Bio.Blast.Applications import NcbiblastpCommandline

blastp_cline = NcbiblastpCommandline(cmd="~/ncbi-blast-2.10.1+/bin/blastp", query="human.fa", db="mouse.fa", evalue=.0001, out="output.xml", outfmt=5)
blastp_cline()
```
changed my first module to this. but now I'm getting an error I don't recognize or google doesn't help:

Comment: raise ApplicationError(return_code, str(self), stdout_str, stderr_str)
Bio.Application.ApplicationError: Non-zero return code 2 from '~/ncbi-blast-2.10.1+/bin/blastp -out output.xml -outfmt 5 -query human.fa -db mouse.fa -evalue 0.0001', message 'BLAST Database error: No alias or index file found for protein database [mouse.fa] in search path [/home/minhlam::]'

Comment: @minjah: that is a typical error you get when trying to blast a protein sequence against a nucleotide database. Blastp is only for blasting PROTEIN sequences against PROTEIN databases. Make sure you have the right program (blastp or blastn) the right input AND the right database

Answer (score 0):

AS you seem to have found out already, the argument `outputfmt` needs to be corrected to `outfmt`. However, there seem to be some more problems here:

A.) It seems you are trying to blast two nucleotide fasta files against each other?
First you need to create a blast database for your reference sequences using `makeblastdb`. THEN you can blast your query fasta against this database

B.) It seems you are trying to use blastp (which is meant for protein sequences) to blast nucleotide sequences against nucleotide references. If blastp finds a nucleotide database instead of a protein database, it tries to find an alias file that refers to the corresponding protein sequences (Hence your error in the comments). Make sure you are selecting the correct blast tool:

- blastn : for nucleotide queries against nucleotide references
- blastp : for protein queries against protein references
- blastx : for nucleotide queries against protein references
- tblastn: for protein queries against nucleotide references